# open URL in the default browser

Tags: java, android, webview

i have a webview where i load an url and when i click the webview i want to open the link in the default browser.I tried to set the WebViewClient and `override shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` method

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.e("BaseFragment", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading  " + url);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
        return false;
    }
```

but it is not called by the webview. Any other ideas to do this?

BaseFragment is an abstract class where i have the following WebViewClient:

```
protected WebViewClient mAddWebViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        float scale = addTopWebView.getHeight() / 170f;
        addTopWebView.setInitialScale((int) (scale * 100f));
        String js = "javascript:(function(){"
                + "document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.height = 'auto';"
                + "document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.width = 'auto';"
                + "})()";
        view.loadUrl(js);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.e("BaseFragment", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading  " + url);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }

};
```

And other fragments which extend this BaseFragment have some webviews and there in onViewCreated method i set the webviewclient:

```
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    addTopWebView = myWebView;
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(mAddWebViewClient);
```

Comment: i don't see anything wrong here (you probably will want to return `true` to avoid loading the page also in the webview, but that is not relevant for now). Can you post more code? (creating the webview, setting the WebViewClient...)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should return true for the external browser.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.e("BaseFragment", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading  " + url);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
    return true;
}
```

If you want to show in a custom webview you shoud override and set the return to false.

Comment: even if i return true it does nothing..the method is not called

Comment: Could you give me more details on how your code works? You want to open a web browser from a fragment? Or could you post a larger chunk of code please?

Comment: i added more explanation